load_model from tensorflow.keras.models can not be imported
I would like to work with EEG pre-trained model. Have just sample script, which for now will re-save model in another format:
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('path_to_model.h5')

# Save it as a SavedModel
model.save('saved_model_path', save_format='tf')

I have error that load_model is not recognized as a part of models class. Then I tried to run the script in isolated environment without PyCharm and have such error:
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'Conv2D' using config={'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'dtype': 'float32', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': 'fan_avg'}}, 'name': 'conv2d', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'dtype': 'float32', 'activation': 'linear', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': 'channels_first', 'padding': 'same', 'strides': [1, 1], 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'filters': 8, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {'dtype': 'float32'}}, 'use_bias': False, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_size': [1, 32], 'input_shape': [None, 1, 60, 151]}.

Exception encountered: <class 'keras.src.initializers.random_initializers.VarianceScaling'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'dtype': 'float32', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': 'fan_avg'}, 'registered_name': None}.

Exception encountered: VarianceScaling.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

whether it's possible to have load_model in the script to work with available models?

Could you please provide the versions of TensorFlow and Keras you're currently using? Sometimes, issues arise due to mismatched versions.
